# Добавить список/массив TextView

Tags: java, android

Мне необходимо создать n TextView. Сейчас я делаю это так:

```
TextView[] txts = new TextView[100];
LinearLayout LL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LL);
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    txts[i] = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    txts[i].setLayoutParams(lp);
    txts[i].setText("Text");
    LL.addView(txts[i]);
};
```

Но что-то получается не так. Не подскажите ли, что не так?

**UPD:** есть ли у кого-либо возможность узнать, какая ошибка выдаётся при исполнении этого кода?

Comment: На первый взгляд создание `LayoutParams` просится в цикл.

Comment: @SergeySolodukhin, проблема не в этом

Comment: @Style-7, проблема была не в этом. Ещё один оправдан

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тебе точно нужно этого делать с помощью [RecyclerView](https://www.fandroid.info/primer-ispolzovaniya-cardview-i-recyclerview-v-android/).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я вижу, что это отличный вариант. Но мне хотелось что-то "поконсерватичнее".

Comment: "поконсерватичнее"? Тогда [Урок 42. Список - ListView](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/82-urok42-spisok-listview.html)

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю проблема в динамическом создании TextView. Попробуйте указать положение TextView на разметке:
lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;

Comment: Оказывается, не в Gravity дело...